# Two differents versions of a jar used by spark-submit

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jar

I'm using spark-submit on Ambari and I need to run some code which uses a different version of a jar than spark-submit already needs.

I have a code sample which uses com.fasterxml.jackson.* with a version > 2.7 and Spark 2.1 uses a version of it when it is initializing with a version 2.6.5

What did I try :

- sbt assembly to get a fat jar
- put the two differents version of the jar in the spark jars directory
- Put the > 2.7 version in the build.sbt

But nothing work, every time Spark initialize with 2.6.5 version so my code can't be ran. If I delete this version and put the > 2.7, then Spark can't be initialized

So I wanted to know if I can specified the version of the library when I do the import in my files .scala ? Or is there another way around ?

Thanks for your time

**EDIT :**

I'm importing this library in my code : *import com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader*

This library needs a > 2.7 version of jackson, so I'm not explicitly importing the jackson libray, but the source code of DataBaseReader needs the jackson library

**EDIT2 :**

From what I understand of the error :

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode.(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/JsonNodeFactory;Ljava/util/List;)V*

It's an method error, it doesn't find the method in the source code. So it really seems to be a version problem. It uses the source code of the native spark jars : the jackson.core.* 2.6.5 meanwhile I really need for this specific code sample the > 2.7 (for example 2.8.8)

Comment: `dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
   "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.7.0"
)` - try to put this to your `build.sbt`

Comment: I tried this but I still have the same error : *java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode.<init>(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/JsonNodeFactory;Ljava/util/List;)V* Could this be coming from the cluster deploy mode ? For now I'm just doing a **sbt compile** and then a **sbt package**

Comment: There are only two ways to work around this: Each requires rebuilding the library you use. Either you rebuild just the jar, and use **dependency shading** to rename/relocate the jackson databind dependency (changing only the build metadata), or you rebuild the library using the version that is contained in Spark - this may entail code changes, of course. There is no way for two versions of a library to be on the classpath of a jvm, if they have the same name.

Comment: The shading seems appropriate for me, but I'm totally new to this... Do I have to add something like this : assemblyShadeRules in assembly ++= Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**" -> "my_conf.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.8.1")
    .inProject
) @RickMoritz

Comment: No, you'd have to use the Maven shade plugin and edit this pom.xml: https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java/blob/master/pom.xml after having checked out the library, then rebuild that project, before importing it into your own project. regarding the technical aspects, I'm afraid you'll have to look elsewhere - otherwise I'd have written that as answer ;(

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar problem: I need `orc-core-1.5.5` but Spark2.3.3 has only `orc-core-1.4.4`. I'm using Maven Shade Plugin, to add `orc-core-1.5.5` into my final jar directly. But when I submit it to spark-2.3.3. It still says ,NoSuchMethod... Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Nope never solved it sadly, don't remember what did I do to avoid the issue :/